# CS0118 framerate is a field but a type was expected

Tags: unity, c#, frame-rate

I'm making a mobile game in Unity and I'm trying to write a script that will set the game to either 30 or 60 frames per second based on a public bool, but I am getting error CS0118 on line 12 with

> fps.framerate is a 'field' but a 'type' was expected.

I am pretty new to Unity so I need help with this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class fps : MonoBehaviour
{
  public fps framerate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
    framerate = GameObject.Find("gameSettings").GetComponent<framerate>(); <= error CS0118
    {
      if (framerate == true)
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
      else
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic syntax error, and the compiler is telling you exactly what you did wrong.

```
framerate = GameObject.Find("gameSettings").GetComponent<framerate>();
```

`GetComponent<T>` needs a *type* passed as its type argument `T`. But `framerate` is not a *type*, it's a *field* (a public member variable). It looks like you meant to write `GetComponent<fps>` here, since `fps` is the name of this class, which is a type.

But even fixing that, this script does not do anything sensible. It looks like you meant to write something more like this:

```
// Classes begin with an uppercase letter.
public class FPS : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You want a boolean variable to control whether to run at 60 FPS.
    // What you had before was an instance of the FPS script, so each script
    // pointed at another copy of the script, with none of them knowing 
    // whether 60 FPS was desired.
    public bool use60FPS;

    void Start () 
    {
        // We don't need to do an expensive search through all our GameObjects
        // for one named "gameSettings" then search its components for an "FPS" script.
        // This script that's running this code IS the FPS script. So just use it.

        if (use60FPS == true) {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
        }
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend working through some more basic programming tutorials until the fundamental syntax of the language makes sense. [Questions about programming syntax, that don't require game development-specific expertise to solve, are usually already answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cs0118&mixed=1).